# PySpark XML to JSON w/ Time Series Data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have almost half a million XML files containing time series data that are about ~2-3MB each and contains around 10k rows of time series data per file. The idea is to convert the XML files into JSON for each unique ID. However, the time series data for each ID needs to be broken down into batches of row size 10 and converted to JSON and written to NoSQL database. Initially, the code was written to iterate over one monolithic dataframe for each ID and increment by row size 10 and then write document to db.

```
def resample_idx(X,resample_rate):
    for idx in range(0,len(X),resample_rate):
        yield X.iloc[idx:idx+resample_rate,:]

# Batch Documents 
    for idx, df_batch in enumerate(resample_idx(df,10))
        dict_ = {}
        dict_['id'] = soup.find('id').contents[0]
        dict_['data'] = [v for k,v in pd.DataFrame.to_dict(df_batch.T).items()]
```

A sample of the JSON document looks as follows:

```
{'id':123456A,
'data': [{'A': 251.23,
          'B': 130.56,
          'dtim': Timestamp('2011-03-24 11:18:13.350000')
         },
         {
          'A': 253.23,
          'B': 140.56,
          'dtim': Timestamp('2011-03-24 11:19:21.310000')
         },
         .........
        ]
},
{'id':123593X,
'data': [{'A': 641.13,
          'B': 220.51,
          'C': 10.45
          'dtim': Timestamp('2011-03-26 12:11:13.350000')
         },
         {
          'A': 153.25,
          'B': 810.16,
          'C': 12.5
          'dtim': Timestamp('2011-03-26 12:11:13.310000')
         },
         .........
        ]
}
```

This works fine for a small sample, but quickly realizing this will not scale when creating the batches. Therefore, looking to replicate this in Spark. Limited experience w/ Spark, but here's what I've attempted to far:

First get all of time series data for all IDs:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(rowTag='log').load("dbfs:/mnt/timedata/")
```

XML Schema

```
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)   
 |-- collect_list(TimeData): array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ColNames: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Units: string (nullable = true)
```

SQL Query to get Spark DataFrame
    d = df.select("_id","TimeData.data",'TimeData.ColNames')

Current Spark DataFrame

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                id  |                data|            ColNames|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|123456A             |[2011-03-24 11:18...|dTim,A,B            |
|123456A             |[2011-03-24 11:19...|dTim,A,B            |
|123593X             |[2011-03-26 12:11...|dTim,A,B,C          |
|123593X             |[2011-03-26 12:11...|dTim,A,B,C          |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Expected Spark DataFrame

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|                id  |               dTime|         A|         B|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|123456A             |2011-03-24 11:18... |    251.23|    130.56|
|123456A             |2011-03-24 11:19... |    253.23|    140.56|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+

+--------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|                id  |               dTime|         A|         B|         C|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|123593X             |2011-03-26 12:11... |    641.13|    220.51|     10.45|
|123593X             |2011-03-26 12:11... |    153.25|    810.16|      12.5|
+--------------------+-------------------+---------- +----------+----------+
```

I only showed data for two timestamps here, but how could I take the DataFrame above and turn into batch JSON files for every nth row (for each id), similarly to how it was done using Pandas shown above? Initially thoughts were performing a groupBy and apply a UDF to each ID? The output would look like the JSON structure above.

XML Structure:

```
<log>
   <id>"ABC"</id>
   <TimeData>
      <colNames>dTim,colA,colB,colC,</colNames>
      <data>2011-03-24T11:18:13.350Z,0.139,38.988,0,110.307</data>
      <data>2011-03-24T11:18:43.897Z,0.138,39.017,0,110.307</data>
  </TimeData>
</log>
```

Note that each ID does not have a fixed number of coNames and that can range between 5-30, depending on the data sources collected for that ID.

Comment: Do you have some sample XML-files? And the output should become the json as showed above, right?

Comment: @TomLous yes, the output would be the same as shown above. Will update with a snippet of the xml file

Comment: Could there be an unmentioned `.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"TimeData"))` somewhere to explain the XML Schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well based on the information this could be a solution. Unfortunately my Python is a bit rusty, but there should be equivalents for all the scala functions here

```
// Assume nth is based of dTim ordering
val windowSpec = Window
  .partitionBy($"_id")
  .orderBy($"dTim".desc)

val nthRow  = 2  // define the nthItem to be fetched

df.select(
  $"_id",
  $"TimeData.data".getItem(0).getItem(0).cast(TimestampType).alias("dTim"),
  $"TimeData.data".getItem(0).getItem(1).cast(DoubleType).alias("A"),
  $"TimeData.data".getItem(0).getItem(2).cast(DoubleType).alias("B"),
  $"TimeData.data".getItem(0).getItem(3).cast(DoubleType).alias("C")
).withColumn("n", row_number().over(windowSpec))
  .filter(col("n") === nthRow)
  .drop("n")
.show()
```

Will output something like

```
+-------+--------------------+------+------+-----+
|    _id|                dTim|     A|     B|    C|
+-------+--------------------+------+------+-----+
|123456A|2011-03-24 11:18:...|251.23|130.56| null|
|123593X|2011-03-26 12:11:...|641.13|220.51|10.45|
+-------+--------------------+------+------+-----+
```

I'll improve the answer if I know a bit more

---

Update

I liked the puzzle, so if I understand the problem correctly, this could be a solution:

I've created 3 xml files with each 2 data records with 2 different ids in total

```scala
val df = spark
  .sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "log")
  .load("src/main/resources/xml")


// Could be computationally heavy, maybe cache df first if possible, otherwise run it on a sample, otherwise hardcode possible colums
val colNames = df
  .select(explode(split($"TimeData.colNames",",")).as("col"))
  .distinct()
  .filter($"col" =!= lit("dTim") && $"col" =!= "")
  .collect()
  .map(_.getString(0))
  .toList
  .sorted

// or list all possible columns
//val colNames = List("colA", "colB", "colC")


// Based on XML colNames and data are comma seprated strings that have to be split. Could be done using sql split function, but this UDF maps the columns to the correct field
def mapColsToData = udf((cols:String, data:Seq[String]) =>
  if(cols == null || data == null) Seq.empty[Map[String, String]]
  else {
    data.map(str => (cols.split(",") zip str.split(",")).toMap)
  }
)

//  The result of this action is 1 record for each datapoint for all XML's. Each data record is key->value map of colName->data
val denorm = df.select($"id", explode(mapColsToData($"TimeData.colNames", $"TimeData.data")).as("data"))

denorm.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id     |data                                                                           |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123456A|Map(dTim -> 2011-03-24T11:18:13.350Z, colA -> 0.139, colB -> 38.988, colC -> 0)|
|123456A|Map(dTim -> 2011-03-24T11:18:43.897Z, colA -> 0.138, colB -> 39.017, colC -> 0)|
|123593X|Map(dTim -> 2011-03-26T11:20:13.350Z, colA -> 1.139, colB -> 28.988)           |
|123593X|Map(dTim -> 2011-03-26T11:20:43.897Z, colA -> 1.138, colB -> 29.017)           |
|123456A|Map(dTim -> 2011-03-27T11:18:13.350Z, colA -> 0.129, colB -> 35.988, colC -> 0)|
|123456A|Map(dTim -> 2011-03-27T11:18:43.897Z, colA -> 0.128, colB -> 35.017, colC -> 0)|
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```scala
// now create column for each map value, based on predef / found columnNames
val columized = denorm.select(
  $"id",
  $"data.dTim".cast(TimestampType).alias("dTim"),
  $"data"
)

columized.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     id|                dTim|                data|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|123456A|2011-03-24 12:18:...|Map(dTim -> 2011-...|
|123456A|2011-03-24 12:18:...|Map(dTim -> 2011-...|
|123593X|2011-03-26 12:20:...|Map(dTim -> 2011-...|
|123593X|2011-03-26 12:20:...|Map(dTim -> 2011-...|
|123456A|2011-03-27 13:18:...|Map(dTim -> 2011-...|
|123456A|2011-03-27 13:18:...|Map(dTim -> 2011-...|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

```scala
// create window over which to resample
val windowSpec = Window
  .partitionBy($"id")
  .orderBy($"dTim".desc)

val resampleRate = 2

// add batchId based on resample rate. Group by batch and
val batched = columized
  .withColumn("batchId", floor((row_number().over(windowSpec) - lit(1)) / lit(resampleRate)))
  .groupBy($"id", $"batchId")
  .agg(collect_list($"data").as("data"))
  .drop("batchId")

batched.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id     |data                                                                                                                                                              |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123593X|[Map(dTim -> 2011-03-26T11:20:43.897Z, colA -> 1.138, colB -> 29.017), Map(dTim -> 2011-03-26T11:20:13.350Z, colA -> 1.139, colB -> 28.988)]                      |
|123456A|[Map(dTim -> 2011-03-27T11:18:43.897Z, colA -> 0.128, colB -> 35.017, colC -> 0), Map(dTim -> 2011-03-27T11:18:13.350Z, colA -> 0.129, colB -> 35.988, colC -> 0)]|
|123456A|[Map(dTim -> 2011-03-24T11:18:43.897Z, colA -> 0.138, colB -> 39.017, colC -> 0), Map(dTim -> 2011-03-24T11:18:13.350Z, colA -> 0.139, colB -> 38.988, colC -> 0)]|
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```scala
// Store as 1 huge json file (drop reapatrition if you can handle multiple json, better for master as well)
batched.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("/tmp/xml")
```

Output json:

```json
{"id":"123593X","data":[{"dTim":"2011-03-26T12:20:43.897+01:00","colA":"1.138","colB":"29.017"},{"dTim":"2011-03-26T12:20:13.350+01:00","colA":"1.139","colB":"28.988"}]}
{"id":"123456A","data":[{"dTim":"2011-03-27T13:18:43.897+02:00","colA":"0.128","colB":"35.017","colC":"0"},{"dTim":"2011-03-27T13:18:13.350+02:00","colA":"0.129","colB":"35.988","colC":"0"}]}
{"id":"123456A","data":[{"dTim":"2011-03-24T12:18:43.897+01:00","colA":"0.138","colB":"39.017","colC":"0"},{"dTim":"2011-03-24T12:18:13.350+01:00","colA":"0.139","colB":"38.988","colC":"0"}]}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I've updated the question above to be more clear. Would like to avoid hard coding the columnNames if possible, as this will vary for each ID.

Comment: @TraceSmith was this what yo intended?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that does not depend on hard-coded column names. Basically, the idea is to explode the `data` and `ColNames` columns to get a 'melted' DF, which we can then pivot to get the form you want:

```
# define function that processes elements of rdd
# underlying the DF to get a melted RDD
def process(row, cols):
    """cols is list of target columns to explode"""
    row=row.asDict()
    exploded=[[row['id']]+list(elt) for elt in zip(*[row[col] for col in cols])]    
    return(exploded)


#Now split ColNames:
df=df.withColumn('col_split', f.split('ColNames',","))

# define target cols to explode, each element of each col 
# can be of different length
cols=['data', 'col_split']

# apply function and flatmap the results to get melted RDD/DF
df=df.select(['id']+cols).rdd\
    .flatMap(lambda row: process(row, cols))\
    .toDF(schema=['id', 'value', 'name'])

# Pivot to get the required form
df.groupby('id').pivot('name').agg(f.max('value')).show()
```